# Can I draw a path using the `--` syntax but still something like `bend right`?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-path

I like the `\draw (a) edge[bend right] (b) ;` way of drawing because it allows me to curve the edge a bit without worrying about specific control points.
I like the `\draw (a) -- (b) -- (c) ;` way of drawing because it's helpful for drawing a sequence of edges in a graph.

Can I combine these somehow to bend the edges using the `--` syntax?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,fill,circle}]

% straight line edges, annoying repetition of "(b)"
\node (a) at (1,4) {} ;  \node (b) at (2,4) {} ;  \node (c) at (3,4.5) {} ;
\draw (a) edge (b) ;   \draw (b) edge (c) ;

% just curve one of them it a bit
\node (a) at (1,3) {} ;  \node (b) at (2,3) {} ;  \node (c) at (3,3.5) {} ;
\draw (a) edge[bend right] (b) ;   \draw (b) edge (c) ;

% straight lines also, less redundant
\node (a) at (1,2) {} ;  \node (b) at (2,2) {} ;  \node (c) at (3,2.5) {} ;
\draw (a) -- (b) -- (c) ;

% i want to do something like this
%\node (a) at (1,1) {} ;  \node (b) at (2,1) {} ;  \node (c) at (3,1) {} ;
%\draw (a) -- [bend right] (b) -- (c) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
```

I know that I can use control points, other constructs to get a curved path, but I want something that doesn't involve coordinates other than the `\node`s so I can move the `\node`s around

Comment: What is wrong with `\draw (a) to [bend right] (b) -- (c) ;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,fill,circle}]

% straight line edges, annoying repetition of "(b)"
\node (a) at (1,4) {} ;  \node (b) at (2,4) {} ;  \node (c) at (3,4.5) {} ;
\draw (a) edge (b) ;   \draw (b) edge (c) ;

% just curve one of them it a bit
\node (a) at (1,3) {} ;  \node (b) at (2,3) {} ;  \node (c) at (2,2) {} ;
\draw (a.center) to[bend right] (b.center) -- (c.center) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is what I was hoping for.  Except that I notice that the alignment is wrong.  If you change the coordinates of (c) to be (2,2) the edge b--c is attached where the previous edge is, instead of aimed at the centre of the vertex (b).  My coordinates were inadvertantly such that the bent edge was aimed straight at the next vertex.

Comment: @mikenewman Better now? Note that nodes have finite sizes. You are in a way abusing nodes (but so do many), in principle you are supposed to use coordinates instead, or, as in my updated answer, play with the centers of the nodes (in this situation).

Comment: Argh!  I knew the (a.center), but forgot it once again... I think because somehow the plain `--` effectively assumes it....